# A question about identical complex power series.

Tags: complex-analysis

My Complex Analysis book says the following:

> Two complex series $c_0+c_1z+c_2z^2+c_3z^3+\dots$ and $d_0+d_1z+d_2z^2+\dots$ are identical if they are identical on infinitely many points converging on $z=0$.

No proof is given. I have thought up a proof, but it seems to work only if all but a finite number of these points occur in the region of convergence of the power series $(c_0-d_0)+(c_1-d_1)z+(c_2-d_2)z^2+\dots$

Is this condition valid in general for the general scenario? Or am I imposing a condition that isn't necessary for this theorem to be true?

Thank you.

Comment: $\sin z$ and $5 \sin z$ are equal at all real integer multiples of $\pi$

Comment: @WillJagy- Yes but those multiples of $\pi$ are not convergent on $0$.

Comment: true....not really sure what your question might be.

Comment: @WillJagy- My question is: is the theorem stated in my book true for ANY sequence convergent on $0$, or is it true for only those seqeuences which mainly lie inside the region of convergence of the difference of the power series?

Comment: Maybe this is what you're looking for: [Identity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem)